# Why aren't these two regular expressions (one with a variable) equivalent?

Tags: python, regex

Here is the original regex, which works fine:

```
regex = r"(https:\/\/www\.snopes+...+?)(&)"
matches = re.findall(regex, soup, re.MULTILINE)
```

I decided I wanted to replace the "snopes" with a variable so I created the following, which is not working:

```
    fact_checker = "snopes"

    regex1 = 'r"(https:\/\/www\.'

    regex2 = '+...+?)(&)"'

    regex3 = regex1 + fact_checker + regex2

    matches = re.findall(regex3, soup, re.MULTILINE)
```

How are regex and regex3 not identical? When I've printed them out they look the same.

Comment: `regex1 = 'r"(https:\/\/www\.'` puts a literal `r` *and `"`) character in the string.

Comment: sorry what language is this in? Please tag it as such

Comment: @CertainPerformance That would make sense. I couldn't figure out another way because of the `"` which works as an escape character and makes it difficult to insert a variable after it. I tried playing around with that but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @billynoah My bad, it's in Python.

Comment: Do you really want for the regex to match `snopes`, `snopess`, `snopesss`, etc? That's what the plus does.

Comment: @tripleee I'm actually trying to get a full url (ex:https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/doj-most-dangerous-vaccine/) and the urls always end in `&` in the soup so this was the easiest way I could think of. Definitely could be improved  :)

Comment: Probably something like `r'https://www\.snopes\.[^&"<>]+&'` then.

Answer (score 2):

You are making the very common mistake of assuming the `r` prefix is somehow part of the value. It is not; it merely tells the Python interpreter what sort of quoting is used in the following string. (Perhaps compare to how `0.0L` is a number in C; the `L` suffix says it's a number of storage type `long`.)

Anyway, the idiomatic way to do what you want is

```
regex = r"(https://www\.{}+...+?)(&)".format(fact_checker)
```

(The slash has no special meaning in regex, so I took out the superfluous backslashes. The regex could no doubt still be improved.)

Comment: This is much more concise than my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
regex1 = r"(https:\/\/www\."

regex2 = r"+...+?)(&)"

regex3 = regex1 + fact_checker + regex2
```